# TimeAgoPipe use in angular component

Tags: angular

I have add to my module {TimeAgoPipe} to app.module.ts and I need to use timeAgo my html component:

```
 <div class="container mt-4">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <h1>Your Profile</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <div *ngIf="editForm.dirty" class="alert alert-info">
                <strong>Information:</strong> You have made changes. Any unsaved changes will be lost !
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="card">
                <img class="card-img-top img-thumbnail" src="{{photoUrl || '../../../assets/user.png'}}" alt="{{user.knownAs}}">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div>
                        <strong>Location:</strong>
                        <p>{{user.city}}, {{user.country}}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <strong>Age:</strong>
                        <p>{{user.age}}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <strong>Last Active:</strong>
                        <p>{{user.lastActive || timeAgo}}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <strong>Member Since:</strong>
                        <p>{{user.created | date: 'mediumDate'}}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer">
                    <button [disabled]="!editForm.dirty" form="editForm" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Save Changes</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <div class="tab-panel">
                <tabset class="member-tabset">
                    <tab heading="Edit Profile">
                        <form #editForm="ngForm" id="editForm" (ngSubmit)="updateUser()">
                            <h4>Description</h4>
                            <textarea name="introduction" rows="6" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="user.introduction"></textarea>
                            <h4>Looking For</h4>
                            <textarea name="lookingFor" rows="6" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="user.lookingFor"></textarea>
                            <h4>Looking For</h4>
                            <textarea name="interests" rows="6" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="user.interests"></textarea>
                            <h4>Location Details:</h4>
                            <div class="form-inline">
                                <label for="city">City</label>
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="city" [(ngModel)]="user.city">
                                <label for="country">Country</label>
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="country" [(ngModel)]="user.country">

                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </tab>
                    <tab heading="Edit Photos">
                        <app-photo-editor [photos]="user.photos" (getMemberPhotoChange)="updateMainPhoto($event)"></app-photo-editor>
                    </tab>
                </tabset>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

After add timeAgo I have error: The pipe 'timeAgo' could not be found.

need this module to check the last activity after installing a component, I can't use it.

what should i change and where is the problem?

app.module.ts

```
import { PreventUnsavedChanges } from './_guards/prevent-unsaved-changes.guard';
import { MemberEditResolver } from './_resolvers/member-edit.resolver';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BsDatepickerModule, BsDropdownModule, TabsModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { JwtModule } from '@auth0/angular-jwt';
import { NgxGalleryModule } from 'ngx-gallery';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavComponent } from './nav/nav.component';
import { AuthService } from './_services/auth.service';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './register/register.component';
import { ErrorInterceptorProvider } from './_services/error.interceptor';
import { AlertifyService } from './_services/alertify.service';
import { MemberListComponent } from './members/member-list/member-list.component';
import { ListsComponent } from './lists/lists.component';
import { MessagesComponent } from './messages/messages.component';
import { appRoutes } from './routes';
import { AuthGuard } from './_guards/auth.guard';
import { UserService } from './_services/user.service';
import { MemberCardComponent } from './members/member-card/member-card.component';
import { MemberDetailComponent } from './members/member-detail/member-detail.component';
import { MemberDetailResolver } from './_resolvers/member-detail.resolver';
import { MemberListResolver } from './_resolvers/member-list.resolver';
import { MemberEditComponent } from './members/member-edit/member-edit.component';
import { PhotoEditorComponent } from './members/photo-editor/photo-editor.component';
import { FileUploadModule } from 'ng2-file-upload';
import {TimeAgoPipe} from 'time-ago-pipe';

export function tokenGetter() {
  return localStorage.getItem('token');
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    RegisterComponent,
    MemberListComponent,
    ListsComponent,
    MessagesComponent,
    MemberCardComponent,
    MemberDetailComponent,
    MemberEditComponent,
    PhotoEditorComponent,
    TimeAgoPipe
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    BsDropdownModule.forRoot(),
    BsDatepickerModule.forRoot(),
    TabsModule.forRoot(),
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
    NgxGalleryModule,
    FileUploadModule,
    JwtModule.forRoot({
      config: {
        tokenGetter: tokenGetter,
        whitelistedDomains: ['localhost:5000'],
        blacklistedRoutes: ['localhost:5000/api/auth']
      }
    })
  ],
  providers: [
      AuthService,
      ErrorInterceptorProvider,
      AlertifyService,
      AuthGuard,
      UserService,
      MemberDetailResolver,
      MemberListResolver,
      MemberEditResolver,
      PreventUnsavedChanges
    ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Please share your TimeAgo pipe code.

Comment: You do not seem to have imported the module for your `TimeAgoPipe`.

Answer (score 1):

Everything you have done looks good to me. The reason it's not working is because of not having full compatibility with some versions of angular. As a workaround you can create your  own pipe overriding the transform method of 'time-ago-pipe'. So, you need to do following steps to make it work,

1. install 'time-ago-pipe'
2. create a custom pipe extending `TimeAgoPipe` (also don't forget to implement `PipeTransform`), which will look like following,

import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

import { TimeAgoPipe } from 'time-ago-pipe';

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'timeAgo',
  pure: false
})
export class TimeAgoExtendsPipePipe extends TimeAgoPipe implements PipeTransform{

  transform(value: string): string {
    return super.transform(value);
  }

}
```

3. now, in the app.module.ts file, add import statement for TimeAgoExtendsPipePipe and add it to declarations array. which may look like following,

   import { TimeAgoExtendsPipePipe } from './time-ago-extends-pipe.pipe';

   @NgModule({
   declarations: [
   ...,
   TimeAgoExtendsPipePipe
   ],
   ...
   })
4. finally, you can use it in your template like following,

   {{hours | timeAgo}}

Note: don't forget to add hours property in the component and you may initialize as follows,`hours = new Date().getHours();`

I hope this is helpful.